# Laravel different styles

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i have one problem i have Article model its haves 5 types and one of the types must have different style in html

model

```
public static function scopeAllNews($query)
    {
        return Article::whereIn('type', ['news', 'interview', 'analytic', 'quote'])->statusOn()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

    }
```

controller

```
public function news()
    {
        $newsFirstLine = Article::allNews()->get()->take(8);
        $newsSecondLine = Article::allNews()->FilterContent($newsFirstLine->pluck('id'))->get();
        $populars = Article::popular();
        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('pages/news/news-list', compact('newsFirstLine', 'newsSecondLine', 'populars', 'articles'));
    }
```

blade

```
<div class="container w-100 d-block d-xs-none">
    <div class="d-flex w-100">
        <span class="fas fa-yellow-bullet text-yellow pr-10px font-size-20"></span>
        <div class="font-size-20 font-size-xs-16 font-bold-caps text-blue-100">@tr('web.news')</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($newsFirstLine as $news_item)
        @include("cards/interviews", [
        'image' => $news_item->image,
        'slug' => $news_item->getUrl(), 
        'title' => $news_item->tr('title'), 
        'created' => $news_item->created_at->format('d.F.Y'),
        'createdHi' => $news_item->created_at->format('H:i'),
        ])
        @endforeach

     @if($articles->type == 'quote')
        @foreach($newsFirstLine as $quote)
        @include("cards/quote", [
        'slug' => $quote->getUrl(),
        'title' => $quote->tr('title'),
        'avatar' => $quote->respondent->image,
        'publicPerson' => $quote->respondent->tr('name'),
        'created' => $quote->created_at->format('d.m.Y'),
        'createdHi' => $quote->created_at->format('H:i'),
        ])
        @endforeach
        @endif
    
    </div>
</div>
@include("home.popularNews")
<div class="container w-100">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($newsSecondLine as $news_item)
        @include("cards/interviews", [
        'image' => $news_item->image,
        'slug' => $news_item->getUrl(),
        'title' => $news_item->tr('title'),
        'created' => $news_item->created_at->format('d.m.Y'),
        'createdHi' => $news_item->created_at->format('H:i'),
        ])
        @endforeach


      @if($articles->type == 'quote')
        @foreach($newsFirstLine as $quote)
        @include("cards/quote", [
        'slug' => $quote->getUrl(),
        'title' => $quote->tr('title'),
        'avatar' => $quote->respondent->image,
        'publicPerson' => $quote->respondent->tr('name'),
        'created' => $quote->created_at->format('d.m.Y'),
        'createdHi' => $quote->created_at->format('H:i'),
        ])
        @endforeach
        @endif
    
    </div>
</div>
```

but it's don't working if type will be quote it must include cards/quote and if its not quote type it must include cards/interviews

what's i'm doing wrong? (

Comment: what you get in `$articles`, can you show one record data?

Comment: The public keyword is used only when declaring a class method.

Since you're declaring a simple function and not a class you need to remove public from your code.

Comment: i'm getting nothing in $articles that's wrong code...

Comment: MRRaja remove public from my code?